# My Swift App drains battery very fast while using Location Manager

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, locationmanager

In my `Swift` application I'm checking user's location and sending it to my backend code.

My code for that is all placed in `AppDelegate` and it looks like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
        #selector(AppDelegate.notificationConfirmationSent),
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: locationUpdKey), object: nil)

   initLocationManager()

   return true
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    location = locations.last
    let coord = location.coordinate
    longitude = coord.longitude
    latitude = coord.latitude
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: locationUpdKey), object: self)
    location_fixed = true;
}


func notificationConfirmationSent()
{

    if(defaults.object(forKey: "uniqueId") != nil) {
        let currentTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        if (currentTime - timeInterval > 30) {
            print("SENDING DATA TO WEBSERVICE FROM NOTIFICATION")
            timeInterval = currentTime
            sendCurrentUserPositionToWebService(self.longitude, latitude: self.latitude, uniqueId: defaults.string(forKey: "uniqueId")!)
        }
    }
}
```

Besides that I'm also using these two methods:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        print("NotDetermined")
    case .restricted:
        print("Restricted")
    case .denied:
        print("Denied")

    case .authorizedAlways:
        print("AuthorizedAlways")
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        print("AuthorizedWhenInUse")
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 200
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func initLocationManager() {
    print("init location manager app delegate")
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        //locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        locationManager.distanceFilter = 200

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

}
```

Now, after using my app for some time the battery drains really fast, also, the whole phone is getting hot. I want to change this behavior and fix it, so the phone only sends the location once (when it's `fixed`) and then does so when there are significant changes to the location.
Can you give me a hint how could I proceed from here and why exactly the battery is draining so fast?

Comment: Nothing drains the battery like saying `startUpdatingLocation` and leaving it on. And that is apparently what you are doing (though you have not shown enough code to know for sure).

Comment: @matt currently I'm also using `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() locationManager = nil` in `applicationWillTerminate, but I guess it's not enough?

Comment: at which other point should I stop updating location?

Comment: You should stop whenever you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as battery drain, run Instruments and see what's consuming the CPU.  My guess is that it isn't the location manager.

As far as only knowing about significant changes, Apple has an API for that.

[startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati)

> Note Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500
>   meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect
>   notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the
>   device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager
>   is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that you would call startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges where you now set location_fixed = true. You will also want to stop the location updates, so your code might look like:

```
location_fixed = true
manager.stopUpdatingLocations()
manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```